# Ability to give favourites alternate titles

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

Often I favourite posts that I find either interesting and/or useful, and may be useful for future reference. However, I have 5 pages of favourites (and I'm sure other users have lots more), and when it comes to finding them I often find it difficult, for several reasons:

1. I can't remember what the question was titled - I have a general understanding of topic/tag, like `Javascript` or `Cocoa` but even for specific problems I sometimes can't remember how the question was phrased
2. The user titled the question in a vague way which doesn't *really* link it to the answer; for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039680/why-cant-i-roll-a-loop-in-javascript) is titled "Why can't I roll a loop in Javascript" which doesn't particularly tie it to the idea of closures, which makes it harder to find if I wanted to link back to it in future.

What I am suggesting is:

- When you favorite a question, you
  have the option to give it an
  alternate title
- This is displayed
  along with the post title in the
  favorites tab, which makes it easier to find for future reference

This way it would be easier to find, because I can find it based on what I specifically found useful or interesting in that question, which may have been different or more specific than what the *user* was focusing on in their question. Perhaps when clicking on the star to favorite the question, one of red boxes (similar to the one shown when flagging a post) could appear with an option to give the bookmark an alternate title, or to leave it blank if you don't want to associate one.

Of course, there is always the bookmark option in the browser, but it'd be nice to be able to keep the favourites on Stack Overflow - then if I'm away or not using my main browser I don't have to go there to find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I think this could be a feature that would be useful in a more sweeping change to the favorites page. It seems right now to me personally that the favorite page has a lot of things in which it could be improved upon to make it something that I and others would get more use out of.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you there, just a suggestion. I guess it's more geared towards the 10% of users that Jeff and Joel talk about who are more dedicated to the site.

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, just edit questions with poor / vague titles and give them good, descriptive titles. Maybe clean up the tags a bit while you're there.

Comment: I was thinking about that as I wrote the post, but for some questions it may change the actual meaning of the question to cater to one individual's needs? But yes, I agree that in some cases the titles/tags need to be changed anyway.

Comment: What if you don't have enough rep?