# Why do people vote more on answers than questions?

Tags: discussion, badges, voting

I noted a fact on Stack Overflow badges.

```
● Nice Answer  × 39355
● Nice Question × 7601
```

(5.2:1 rate)

```
● Good Answer  × 6433
● Good Question × 1199
```

(5.3:1 rate)

```
● Great Answer  × 712
● Great Question × 105
```

(6.8:1 rate)

All in all, since the badges are awarded for the same amount of accumulated votes in each category, it appears that people tend to vote more for the answers than the questions...

Just a thought...

Comment: This question has been discussed quite a bit on meta before...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-rating-questions seems to be the definitive tome on the subject.

Comment: yap, duplicate..

Comment: Did you take into account the number of questions vs. the number of answers? Questions likely average three or four answers, so that could explain some of the disparity.

Answer (score 5):

A question is neither wrong or right.  It's a question.

Answers, however, can be rated on a number of scales relating to the question - right/wrong, appropriate/inappropriate, elegant/inelegant, etc.

So the answers are naturally going to get more votes than the questions.

Further, there's no real benefit to upvoting the question - it doesn't place it any higher or lower in any normal listing (until it hits hundreds of votes), it doesn't push it back on the front page, etc.  It's the equivalent of saying, "Me too!" to the question, but nothing more.

Answers change significantly in ordering (for most users) based on voting.

Comment: You are seriously underrating questions. Also, me disagrees about *it's nothing other than 'me too'*. Sometimes people will vote simply because the question is clear or useful or is humorous or interesting or is well-written...