# Personalized tab: show people questions they want to see

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface, views, tabs

I feel like this must be a duplicate, but I couldn't find it.

It would be awesome if SO solved the [Netflix problem](http://www.netflixprize.com). In other words, it would be nice to have a tab of the home/questions/unanswered page which prioritized questions *you are likely to vote up based on your previous voting history and the voting histories of users with similar tastes*. Aside from being thoroughly excellent, this feature would help solve the problem that [people don't vote on questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions). It would clarify the meaning of an upvote: it means, "I want to see questions like this."

The main objection I anticipate is that it would be computationally intensive and require heavy querying of the database. The load could be lightened by requiring 1k (or maybe even 10k) reputation, like the [show total number of votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/show-total-votes-or-up-down-votes) feature.

Comment: The "dumb version" is mostly already there: edit your interesting and ignored tags.  I have 10 interesting and 56 ignored tags.

Comment: @Roger: I mostly agree that the "dumb version" is not so interesting. Though you may actually have the "wrong" interesting/ignored tags. Based on your voting history, it may turn out that you're interested in (or would like to ignore) tags you might not have thought of.

Comment: I think the dumb version will be useless. For the rest, +1. It's unlikely to be implemented though because it's a major feature and (although it might just be a false impression) since I joined (half a year ago) only minor features/tweaks have been implemented.

Comment: I've edited out the "dumb version" of the feature since it's dumb and I'd rather it not draw focus from the real request.

Comment: I would prefer such a feature over the current interesting tags, especially on Super User having the Windows tag is just useless...

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you work up something from the data dump? It should have enough information for you to test out an algorithm.

Note that netflix recently awarded a one million dollar prize for this sort of algorithm.

http://www.netflixprize.com/

Comment: Ok, you caught me. I haven't read those papers and I don't know how hard it would be to code such a feature. I can still dream, can't I? If I do read the papers or otherwise produce a decent candidate algorithm, I'll update the feature-request. But note that no amount of digging in the database would allow me to implement this on the client side because the algorithm would use very recent votes (of other users) on very recent questions, not some kind of machine analysis of the question to compare it to what I've liked in the past.

Comment: @Jeff: I would, but how can I? I would need to know voting data, which is not in the dump