# regarding votes

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do you vote on questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63181/why-do-you-vote-on-questions)

why you are using voting-up option for question

Comment: Huh? Can you please elaborate/argument a bit more?

Comment: I'm very tempted to use the voting- *down* option for questions. :)

Comment: I notice that this is very strongly resembling the [first revision of this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/63181/revisions).

Comment: Voting to close as noise, because it's impossible to determine what the question is asking. (There are multiple _possible_ interpretations, but choosing one would be pure speculation.)

Answer (score 5):

To indicate whether the question is useful/clear/good or useless/unclear/bad.

Comment: That's indeed basically what the tooltips of the vote arrows are telling.

Comment: Um... "useful/clear/ **god** "?

Comment: @Richard, fixed.

Comment: ok........there is a voting down option also........then why is flag there?