# Can't see visited username as link in protected question

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I encountered a strange bug where `<span>` was being used instead of `<a>`. While viewing [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953/178816) which was linked in a new question recently posted, I noticed that I could not click on one of the names. Upon inspection of the html, I came across this:

```
<span class="comment-user">Kyralessa</span>
```

I thought it was odd, and maybe that the user was deleted. However, I then noticed that all users which I had previously visited their profile had this same structure. Such as:

```
<span class="comment-user">Rob Cooper</span>
```

When inspecting users which I had not visited, the correct markup was shown.

```
<a href="/users/1337/brad-gilbert" title="7977 reputation" class="comment-user">Brad Gilbert</a>
```

I am not sure what causes this, and I do not see it on StackOverflow nor in normal Meta posts.

I cannot see names as links, for users who I have viewed their profile, in protected meta posts and/or community wiki posts.

I found this one as well which exhibited the same issue: [Why aren't people voting for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see that because it was migrated from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75296/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs?noredirect=1) and when a question gets migrated to another site, if users don't have an account there, they will get only Name (from the site they were migrated) as credit and not full link to their "new" profile.

If you make, afterwards, your account on new site you will get credited for answers, but not for comments. Comments will be link-less.

If you have your account created on migrated site you will get full link to your profile/their profile.

They don't get their accounts auto created on new site.

So in short: This is the expected behavior, it's not a bug, it's a feature that questions can be migrated within network and users get some credit for their activity.

To get the users profile you have to gain 10k reputation on Stackoverflow, go to [Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9953) and click the migrated site:

> ### **migrated** from [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75296/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs?noredirect=1)   Jul 27 '09 at 10:57

Comment: True, here is the [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5486/kyralessa) of one of those users. You can also go the users tab and search for that user.