# Electorate badge wording vs badge progress

Tags: discussion, badges, electorate-badge

The description of badge is "Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions"

So, my understanding is that a user should do 600 votes (on question and answers) and at least 25% of them should be on questions.

My votes count on SO is 231 on questions and 190 on answers.

If I look at Badge process under Review, it shows me a bargraph with 231 from 600, which makes me think that only votes on questions counts for this badge.

Is wording wrong or is badge progress wrong?

Comment: "Voted on 600 **questions**"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You misunderstood the wording.

Voting on 600 **questions** counts like the descriptions says.

But you should not only have that votes because you already voted on millions of posts and some of them were questions.

It is a badge to award your voting on questions. That badge was introduced [because people all the time vote on answers but often forget to vote on questions too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions).

That is why 25% of your votes should be on questions. Meaning **you can only have a 75% vote on answers**, not more to get the badge. That is a second condition to make sure you have a fair share of voting for questions, not only for answers and a bit of questions.

Answer (score 7):

## Yes.  the wording is correct.

You need to have voted on at least 600 *questions* and then have 25% of all your votes on questions.

I think part of the reason this badge is offered is to get more people to look at new and unanswered questions.

Just keep voting!  It's what makes the site run!