# Does Votes of Answers affect votes of Questions and/or vice-versa?

Tags: discussion, voting

After reading [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions), I asked myself the following questions:

> Do answer votes affect question votes?
>
> Do question votes affect answer votes?
>
> Why?

Comment: Are you saying that if a bad question is asked, even if a good answer is given it should be affected negatively? You seem to indicate that votes correlate with importance when they actually correlate to quality.

Comment: @JoshMein wow, you opened my eyes. Please check the edit i did to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to indicate that votes correlate with importance when they actually correlate to quality.

If a question is not worded well or is not clear it should be down-voted; but if someone miraculously provides the correct answer or the community likes it, the user should be rewarded. The up-votes from the good answer should not be shared or benefit the question in any way.

Comment: So I was completely wrong about what the votes correlate with. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. The votes have no direct effect on each other.

In regards to importance and votes - I would say this is not a correlation (or rather, I don't really understand what you mean by "important" in this context).

The fact is, if a *question* gets lots of upvotes, it will draw more attention - so any answers to it, by association is already getting more attention. So... it already happens.