# Why some posts have all community-wiki answers?

Tags: discussion

I saw some questions that are strange in that all answers for them are community wikis. Examples:
[Why aren't people voting for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions?rq=1)
[Hidden Features of Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/hidden-features-of-xcode?lq=1)
[What Xcode keyboard shortcuts do you use regularly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402174/what-xcode-keyboard-shortcuts-do-you-use-regularly)

Why are they like this? And what's the purpose behind it?

Answer (score 3):

Because the question itself is CW - a CW question can only have CW answers.

Comment: [CW question with normal answers](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/6/42)

Comment: @3ventic: Huh... either that's a bug, or the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) is wrong, because it says that can only happen for old questions that were CW'ed before the current behavior was introduced.

Comment: The post was edited too many times; if the answers were posted before the question got converted you'll end up with that @3ventic.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards "Note that when a question is made CW after answers have already been posted, all existing answers are automatically converted to CW too" is what the [FAQ answer says](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: According to [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), the correct answer should be: `The question generates more than 30 answers (15 on Super User and Programmers, 60 on Code Golf). In this case, the question and all answers will enter community mode, as will any future answers.`