# Upvote an Answer – Upvote the Question as well

Tags: discussion, voting

I was wondering if there should be the policy of upvoting the question when upvoting an answer, and why it is not encouraged.

Because if the answer helped, for sure I reached there because of the question. The question is also an important part of solving the puzzle.

What do SO experts say on this?

**Edit: 6 Dec 2018**

On Stack Overflow do we not say that if you like the answer upvote question as well?

If that is true - how is that different from my question above?

Comment: wow < 20 secs and i get a -1, getting demoralized on meta :( cant dare to ask another question here..

Comment: No, no and... no. So: no.

Comment: I can't even start to explain why it's a bad idea.

Comment: I would wait to see understand why peopel think is bad idea (before i delete my second post on meta :'( )

Comment: Then wait. Nobody's making you delete your question.

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Overflow! See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on MSO are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. People are expressing their opinion on your proposition here.

Comment: you mean < 2 mins got -2 , if this is live for some time more down vote will make virtual reputation == 0 , should i not worry for that?

Comment: Actually you're lucky, usually such questions can easily go down to -10 in few minutes. I'll write something up if I'll have time and nobody else will do it. Oh, and Bart just did it while I was writing this comment. :-)

Comment: I would suggest you [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying) if you care about meta rep.

Comment: TAKE THAT @ShadowWizard with your chatty comments. :p

Comment: @Antony thanks that is useful - specially "newbies wait before suggetion"

Comment: This is also relevant to meta voting; [The meaning of down-votes in meta vs. stackoverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/the-meaning-of-down-votes-in-meta-vs-stackoverflow)

Comment: @RichardTingle your comment helped thanks for insight.

Comment: Hello , Today I saw a message on SO that reads , up vote the question and answer if it helped !... Thats's the same I suggested

Comment: I find your question to be perfectly reasonable, and you are not the first to point out this aspect. Without questions, there cannot be great answers, while it's often the case that great questions do not attract great answers precisely because they tend to be more difficult to answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA you have described it in very nice words. with that I am looking for is - years back we said its wrong idea (with 18 down votes) now we have the same thing implemented which we as SO said not. 

What Changed ? How and with what discussion and understanding now we at SO are promoting that upvote question also ?

I want to know what changed.

Comment: `now we have the same thing implemented which we as SO said not.` it's a little difficult for me to understand what you are saying, can you please find the source, and post the link in a comment. P.S I rarely, if ever, visit SO. This is not SO, this is Meta. I'm sorry, I am confused by your comment.

Comment: Related (maybe you were thinking of this post): [Why aren't people voting for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure, to get good answers, you need a question first. However, good or great answers can still be given to bad, or poorly researched questions.

So while I'll surely upvote the brilliant answer, the question itself might not necessarily deserve it.

Comment: hmm right, I agree and clearly get your view point. :)

Comment: Plus with this suggestion, we could never get the Reversal badge. Granted, getting it on non-meta questions is already ridiculously hard.