# We need to upvote questions more

Tags: discussion, voting

I've noticed several questions that I feel are clear and show that the asker put in effort. But the questions are not upvoted by users.

We are not asked to upvote only the questions that are interesting; we are asked to upvote questions that are clear and showed that the asker put in effort:

[image]

Why don't we upvote questions more? We should upvote any question that is useful and clear and shows that the asker put in effort. This will not only encourage new users, it will also increase the likelihood that a question will be answered.

---

It seems to me that the questions that are upvoted most are the obscure ones. Somehow, it seems that users feel that interesting questions are the questions that surprise them, but there are many other questions out there that are interesting, just not as obscure / surprising.

Comment: Maybe it's related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9508/253846

Comment: @Fllo This is related, but I'm also pointing at the mouseover on the upvote button. This is more specific

Comment: I upvote when I consider a question to be _great_ -- most of the time, I find that's not the case. Either my feelings towards the question is lukewarm, or it's absolutely horrible.

Comment: People tend to use votes in a manner similar to _likes_ on a social network.  You'd often find FAQs to be upvoted more than a well-researched and good question.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Lukewarm questions should be upvoted. As long as a question is well-written and shows effort, I think it should be upvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've noticed several questions that I feel show that the asker put in
>   effort and wrote a clear question. But the question is not upvoted by
>   users.

If *you* feel that the question is good, then you should upvote it. Other people don't have to upvote it, because voting on SO is always the user's decision.

> We are not asked to upvote only the questions that are on interesting questions, we are asked to upvote questions that are clear and showed that the asker put in effort

It seems like you touched upon some reasons why people vote for questions. Some people upvote questions because they are helpful or interesting or cool or stupid. That's really their own choice. (Yes, there will sometimes be an upvoter who wants to upvote the bad questions just to feel, um, unique.)

> It seems to me that the questions that are upvoted most are the obscure ones.

Well, let's look at the top upvoted questions:

[image: top questions]

These questions may appear to be "obscure" at first glance, but to those who use the languages mentioned, these questions may be upvote-worthy.

Overall, I disagree with your stance on voting- voting is used however people want to use it, which is the way it should be.

Comment: I find it interesting that you disagree with my stance because it appears to be the same as the site developers given the text for the mouseover on the upvote button. I wonder why they would say that if they did not want us to upvote whenever we found such questions.

Comment: Your answer shows much more research effort and clarity than my question. :-)

Comment: @Quincunx Lol thanks :)

Comment: @quincunx I disagree because I believe that the tooltip is a guideline, not a rule. Also, take a peek at meta's tooltips. Do you think that they really apply? Does a discussion need to show research effort? Does a post on unicorns need to show research effort? :)

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that "Useful" to some extent implies interesting.  For the most part, if it is a useful question, then it will be interesting.  If the question is unlikely to be useful to anyone other than the asker, then it isn't interesting.

That said, I do think that it is fairly common for people to forget to upvote questions in general, but I don't think the fact that "interesting" questions get more upvotes is a particular sign of an issue.

Comment: IMO if the question is unlikely to be useful to anyone other than the asker, then it should be closed as "too localized"

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with OP. Why? Because if you read the Help Center about [question-banning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), you would see that

> The exact formula for the bans is not disclosed, but users are only banned if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, **ZERO-VOTED**, or deleted posts. One or two bad posts will not cause you to be blocked from using the site.

If the asker got many 0 score posts, they will be banned from questioning. That is why we need to upvote the questions: if we think every user is important for our community. Like one of the Stack Exchange mottos:

> We aren't running it, the **Community** does.

Comment: Thanks for edit Quincunx