# why isn't a user prompted to upvote a question when they upvote an answer?

Tags: feature-request

The Powers That Be have seen fit to prompt users to upvote questions and answers that they find helpful.  Presumably the intent behind that is to provide more momentum towards achieving the ultimate goal of a site replete with high quality questions and answers.  However, since the stats reported [elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions) seem to reflect that people simply vote for the "best" answer and get back to their real, paying work without upvoting the question (I know, I've done it myself), it seems that it would be worth putting in a little popup that opens immediately upon the answer being upvoted that asks the user if they would also like to upvote the question, or provide some brief feedback as to why not.  Then the OP can be alerted to improve the question, and eventually bounty hunters can be alerted to come in and clean it up if the OP neglects to.

Comment: I can think of lots of times when I've upvoted an answer and *downvoted* the question. One is not at all indicative of the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't people voting for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9508/why-arent-people-voting-for-questions)

Comment: @gnat really? Feature request asking to do something very specific is duplicate of a discussion about something? No. Like I said before, using this logic we can create one question titled "Ask anything here" and close all questions on this site as duplicate of that. I mean, this request is bad and I downvoted, but it was never asked before.

Comment: OK, I've rewritten the request, since there have been so many objections here and elsewhere to full automation.

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes a question is bad -- too vague, a one-liner with no effort, barely intelligible, etc -- and yet somebody comes along and produces a good answer anyway, despite the low quality of the question.  There's even a badge for this kind of situation, Reversal.

So no, upvoting an answer should not cast any automatic votes on the question.  If both the question and answer are good, upvote both.  If not, don't.

Answer (score 2):

That simply does not follow.

For example, I downvoted your question as it's absurd, but upvoted @MonicaCellio's answer as I rather like it.

The voting mechanism is an expression of personal opinion but because it is statistically correlated with the quality of the thing being voted upon, it is a useful way of attributing credibility or otherwise to questions and answers. It is possible to like an answer but not like a question, and the voting mechanism reflects that.

Comment: I can't downvote your answer because of rep.  But you do not understand the definition of the word "absurd", and you are abusing your power to downvote just because you didn't agree with the question.  I just saw a question on searching within braces in vi which is NOT vague, NOT a one-liner, and NOT barely intelligible.  The question had no upvotes, and the answer had six, and yet it was exactly the kind of question that stackoverflow was created for.

Comment: That's now meta works: you downvote a question if you disagree with the premise. It's not the same as SO. Above everything else, voting should not be taken personally!

Comment: Well, if you had said "I downvoted because it's too similar to this and this and this" or possibly even "because you haven't thought it all the way through" that would have been legitimate.  But calling it absurd is not.  And disagreeing with the premise seems unlikely, unless you have also taken it upon yourself to go and be the lone downvote for the similar questions which have really high upvotes.  I just read elsewhere that it cost you rep to downvote me -- hope it was worth it.

Comment: @Bathsheba only problem with your logic is that you lose rep - and thus the ability to vote on meta issues - if people downvote your q/a's. So it is most definitely personal as it can take away someone's ability to express opinions here via voting.