# Go back to previously visited post

Tags: support

After searching for unanswered posts, I pick one favorite post that I think I can answer. However, to answer this question, I have to look up in all my recent posts or do some google search. When I get back with an answer, I couldn't find the post. I try to use **BACK** button in a browser but sometimes it helps, sometimes it doesn't. I know there is a favorite section that we can mark. But most of time, I forget to do that. So, is there any history list that we can see visited posts to get back to them easily? Thanks.

Comment: Are multiple tabs not an option?

Comment: Thanks. It would be great idea, but I already keep alot of opening tabs in my browser.

Comment: There is nothing beyond the `Favorites`.  I've often hoped for similar functionality, so I think there is a need, but I also believe this has been suggested as a feature request before and declined because your browser history already does the same thing.

Comment: @KhanhTran: If you keep a lot of tabs open then one more won't hurt, right?

Comment: I know I'm asking the obvious, but *just* to be sure: you know about your browser's history? (Of course, that doesn't work cross browser asked requested in [Add a “recently viewed” tab in the user account page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67675/add-a-recently-viewed-tab-in-the-user-account-page), but it seems you're not looking for that.)

Comment: Not what I was thinking of, but here is a [meta-tag:feature-request] for this functionality: [Personal history of recently viewed questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78099/182513)

Comment: And another [meta-tag:feature-request] [Tracking the questions you've recently viewed or visited](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30500/182513)... I've voted on this specifc one before, so I believe this is the question I was thinking of earlier.  Not declined though, so I guess this is a "we haven't decided if it is worth the effort to implement or not"

Comment: @Arjan: I dow know about the browser history. But it lists all visited contents including personal profile page, search tag etc. If we can focus on visited posts only, it will be great.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Thanks for letting me know. It will be nice if we have this feature. Thanks for all feedbacks.

Comment: @psubsee2003, [Nick wrote 1.5 years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67675/add-a-recently-viewed-tab-in-the-user-account-page/116315#116315) *"This would involve tracking a tremendous amount of data on the site databases, a transcriptional load that has no comparison currently"* so I'm afraid that, even though not tagged declined yet, it won't happen soonish...

Comment: Just leave a comment Or even just leave a vote on the post and you will be able to track it back

Comment: Thanks @Arjan I did not find that one in my searching, so I think that  pretty much covers the "when will this be implemented" question.

Comment: @HugoDozois Please *don't* leave a comment if you have nothing worth commenting. There's nothing more annoying than "Commenting for future reference" and "Hold on I'm working on an answer" comments.

Comment: @Juhana well if you know you can answer a question by doing just some basic research (as stated in the post) you can for sure give a basic answer to start with in a comment. But I do agree that leaving "future ref" or what ever like that is bad.

Answer (score 2):

If you do most anything on a post you can look in the Activity tab of your User Profile, but if you only looked at it, then there is nothing keeping track of that.