# Allow marking a question for answering later on the apps

Tags: feature-request, android-app, ios-app, mobile-app

This is like [Add "Answer Later" Tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4719/270345), but specifically for the mobile apps. When on the Android app, often I see a question for which I can think of a good answer, but writing it with proper references, or with properly indented multi-line code is cumbersome on my mobile. I try to make a mental note to answer them when I get to a PC, but I frequently forget.

I could misuse the favourites feature like the other question's OP does. But the mobile apps could really benefit from this.

It would be nice if I could mark the questions, and then the next time I visit the site on a desktop browser, it would show up as notifications or something.

(I'm not a iOS user, but I presume the iOS app doesn't have this either.)