# Organize your favorites

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, navigation

> **Duplicate:**  [Better Favourites Organisation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/better-favourites-organisation)

I'm always favoriting a question for a particular reason. Personal interests, problems I encounter in my own work or things I'd like to solve long-term. Some are related to platforms that I work with, or topics I need to learn someday.

I would like a simple system to organize these favorites, much like an email inbox. A list of favorite "folders" where you can drag-n-drop favorites into would make favorites easy to retrieve later. When you mark a question as a favorite, can go into an "unsorted" folder.

Comment: Duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/better-favourites-organisation

Comment: Its not a duplicate because I'm proposing a specific idea, not asking for any.

Comment: But Steven Lowe posted your idea in that thread already: "simpler solution: organize your favorites into 'folders'" and it already has some upvotes in a thread that is already receiving attention.

Answer (score 2):

How about just being able to tag favorites, with a search of tags? Seems less complex and could probably reuse code and user behavior that's already in use.

Comment: Like Gmail's labels, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's kind of what i had in mind. But also like StackOverflow (et al)'s tags.