# Allow grouping of favorite questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bookmarks

There are many, many old posts on meta asking for suggestions on how to better organize favorites.  [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15504/create-a-better-way-to-organize-favorites), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14086/organize-your-) and [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/better-favourites-organisation), among others.

This is not meant to be an open discussion on how to improve favorites, but rather a specific feature request that I'd like feedback on.

---

I would love to see a feature added that would let users arbitrarily create "groups" of favorites, and drag individual *favorited* questions under these groups.  I have about 2 pages of favorites (I know others have *much* more), and finding an individual one is quite difficult, especially since the specific question title is usually forgotten.  I just added [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638853/where-can-i-practice-making-ajax-calls) to my favorites, since I liked Andrew Whitaker's answer, and might want to come back and look at it later; I'd love to add this to a group called, say, "Useful Code".

I've favorited other posts since they had neat tricks in them, or because there were answers written on interesting theoretical computer science topics.  Having different groups for all these areas would be immensely helpful in finding posts later.

Comment: I would be happy if I could just *search* my favorites.

Comment: @Robert - that would be better than nothing, but with some of the amazing changes I've been seeing the SE team make, the above should be relatively easy.

Comment: No good deed goes unpunished. :)

Comment: @Robert - I hope that comment doesn't cause Nick Craver to come hunt me with a salad fork...

Comment: This post is not nearly contentious enough for me to earn any rep on.

Comment: I have favorited your feature request :-)

Comment: SALAD FORK ENGAGE!  Seriously though, I'll be taking another look at this in the coming weeks, as soon as rep bugs are finished and Dalgas and I get to the OR backup web tier, next is moving search onto some centralized servers along with the tag engine (Marc's already working on this).

Comment: @Nick - sweet!  Should this be status:planned???

Comment: @AdamRackis - Not yet, I have an *idea* of how to do this, whether it'll perform well is another matter...will have to code it up and test it.  The performance of search will be very, *very* different on the service boxes (the indexes are moving into memory, speeeeeeeeeeed), so we'll have to see what happens.

Comment: +1, it is a shame I use a `.txt` for grouping really important things

Comment: @NickCraver I guess that was "in the coming **6-8** weeks". Any update?

Comment: A related post: [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944). (One answer mentions a GreaseMonkey script available on Stack Apps - but I did not manage to get it working: [Favourites Enhancer: Tag favourites and add personal notes](https://stackapps.com/q/6215).)

Comment: @NickCraver Back in 2012 you left here some comments about this feature request. If you remember, could you maybe post an answer describing the ideas you had - so that other users can give some feedback in them. (If something like this is considered for implementation at some point in the future, the discussion here might serve as an inspiration.)

Comment: I would say that the planned changes are in this direction: [Bookmarks Are Evolving Into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019).

Answer (score 4):

With the launch of the [Saves feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves) recently, this is now possible. Custom lists can be created to organize your favorite saved content (now supporting saving answers as well!) As such, I've added the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) label.

Answer (score 3):

While they’re not *arbitrary* groups, your favorite questions are already sorted into groups — they’re just normal question tags. You can search for:

```
Infavorites:mine [sporks]
```

to find all your favorite spork questions. In fact, because this is a regular search, you can use any [advanced or non-advanced search feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) that you would normally use to find a question.

(And if you can’t find the question about bread you’re looking for when you search for `[butter-knife] Infavorites:mine toast` you could consider editing the question to add more relevant keywords — hopefully you’ll help someone else find the question too.)

Comment: The site tags are not sufficient for grouping the bookmarks. That's only if I want to find all Java questions I've bookmarked. I cannot do anything to separate *duplicate targets* from *questions of personal interest*. The latter category can very well be split into several: "want to answer" (but I'll probably do it later), "want to refer to" (no answering - useful information, though), "want to delete" (can't right now, I'll have to wait), and more. That's not based on the properties of a question but *my intent* when I bookmarked it.