# Allow title aliases for our favorite posts

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I've noticed there have been requests to 'favourite' specific answers before. However, it'd be great if we could rename the title of posts we have favourited so that it's easier to find what we're looking for. Of course, the new name would be only visible to our account and wouldn't rename the actual post title.

Sometimes I favourite a thread, simply because there was a useful comment in that thread rather than the question or answer itself. When I'm looking for that comment, I have no idea which thread it's in and so it would be useful if I could rename the 'favourite' from the thread's title to my own description so that it's easy to remember why I favourited that thread and find what I'm looking for.

Edit - To clarify the reason for the alias. Say for example, a comment provides a link to an interesting article I'd like to read later. That article fits in the context of the thread, so I don't want to bookmark is separately in my browser. Six months down the line, and fifty more favourites added, I want to find that comment again. Using title aliases, I can just look for the favourite titled 'Article talking about XYZ'. Clicking that will take me to the original thread, with full context. Advantage of this method over attaching notes, depending on how the notes are implemented, is that you can immediately see the titles whilst scrolling. If I have to click on a button to see the notes attached to the favourite, that could take some time if I have hundreds of favourites.

Comment: Looks a lot like [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4777/148672)

Comment: I guess that's similar - achieves the same goal by the looks of it. However, implementation wise, I can imagine the ability to add a descriptive name may be much simpler to add than a folder hierarchy system.

Comment: Well I was talking about the "tag your favorites as you wish" part.

Comment: Oh I see. Tags would be good, but I'd prefer a custom description. Unless that's what the person meant in which case, yes, seems to be the same request. I took 'tags' to mean the standard tags available when posting a new thread.

Comment: This would be useful mostly because many questions have crappy titles which could benefit from editing anyway.

Comment: This sounds like it would just be confusing. Why would you want your version of the *exact same question* to have a different title than the question's *actual* title? Wouldn't it be better just to implement a [grouping of favorites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125180/a-feature-to-let-us-organize-favorites-more-easily), or allow you to [add a personal note/comment to a favorite question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75944/favorites-improvements)?

Comment: Because the question, answer, and title may be irrelevant to the reason I favourited it. However, your personal note/comment link is quite similar. I guess it's a case of how it's implemented and how easy it is to see. For example, if I had to click on a favourite to see the note, I'd be clicking through potentially hundreds of favourites. If, on the other hand, the notes were visible immediately (as a title alias would be), I can just scroll down the page and quickly find what I'm looking for. It's also an easier implementation than a fully indexed search feature, albeit not as powerful.