# 'Favorite lists' feature proposal

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A feature to let us organize Favorites more easily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125180/a-feature-to-let-us-organize-favorites-more-easily)

It would be great if each user's favorites could be organized into personal lists as the user prefers. For instance like youtube where you can create playlist of your own.

Thus user can store question posts according to the manner that caught his attention and thus find it quickly later.

For example it might be a question regarding a database but one of the answers provides an ajax pattern that caught the user's attention and the question was added to their favorites.

In time this info would take effort to find if user has a long favorites list, since its labels and headings point to 'database'.

Comment: Please don't abuse code formatting for non-code elements. It's not a general highlighting/emphasis tool.