# Create a better way to organize favorites

Tags: feature-request, tags, bookmarks

I've got six pages of favorites on Stack Overflow. Many of those questions are on different topics. I'd really like to have some way of organizing them.

Of course those questions are already tagged so that should be enough, but I can't find any way of showing only favorites with a certain tag.

If it's possible, how do I do that? If it's not possible, then please implement that :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously the developers could add more features to organize 'favorites' but as a solution to your problem...

**Consider using RSS feeds instead**. You will have all your "favorite" questions archived in one place (complete with all the answers). As a bonus you can use the RSS reader's built-in organizing features to group, tag, and search through your RSS questions.

It works great for me. I use [Google Reader](http://reader.google.com).

Comment: RSS seems something a bit more dynamic to me. Just having a feed with no updates isn't something I'm fond of. I might as well make it a bookmark in my browser but that would defeat the point of actually having favorites on the trilogy sites.

Comment: @haikus: +1, using an RSS reader is not a solution, it's just a workaround

Comment: @Robert are you suggesting that Stack Overflow has an RSS feed for our favorites?  If so, how do I access it?

Comment: @MikePennington: This is a very old answer by the way, and much of SE has been greatly improved. I think what I was suggesting was using the 'question feed' at the bottom of posts  (i.e. your favorites) to save interesting questions offline. You can then use your reader's features to organize those posts however you want rather than the developers duplicating that functionality. Truth is, I haven't been using these offline features in quite awhile. Search has improved, tagging has improved, browser and note-taking applications have improved; I just don't use 'favorites' and RSS feeds anymore.

Comment: @RobertCartaino, Thanks for the context... I have been diligently trying to find some way to hack around the lack of "infavorites:" search box capability.  I guess my only option at this point is a SEDE query

Comment: @Robert: so now that Google reader will die on July 1, would you concede that there is some value in having better built-in tools for this?

Comment: Yep.. "Google Reader has been discontinued." from that very link in the answer.  So much for external tools.  That's my issue as well... yeah, I can bookmark all I want, but I would much rather keep all of my SO-related stuff in one place... on SO.

Answer (score 6):

At the moment there isn't much in the way of organizing other than the built-in sorting methods and then searching through your favorites.

I wouldn't mind seeing something that would enable use to put our bookmarks/favorites into a folder system. If there were better ways to organize I may feel tempted to use the feature more often. Right now I don't regularly mark things as favorites because there just doesn't seem to be a real point to unless I need to reference something quickly.

Comment: +1 I would love to see either folders or labels (sortable). That would cover my use-cases perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you can search for infavorites:mine *list of tags*, but it would be more useful and easy if there was a tag search filter right on the favorites page.

Comment: The option `infavorites:mine` was implemented in August 2010, but is [no longer supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76449/new-meta-search-engine-help-us-test) when the new search is introduced early 2011.

Comment: Wait a minute, it seems to work even now.  Sort of.  It has at least one bug.

Comment: Thanks! I needed in basic form atleast this - `infavorites:mine [sitecore]` but what suprising feature is `infavorites:mine [sitecore] mvc` filters questions having MVC (i.e. keyword search) works. :D Now I know there is help link for search support in the search result page it self named "Advanced Search Tips".