# Is there any way I can organize my favorite questions on StackOverflow using self-defined categories?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-watching, bookmarks

I use StackOverflow as a core learning tool and questions posted by others(as well as comments) have much-sought information and nuances.Also,the questions posted by me are likely to increase in numbers with time.I already have nearly a hundred favorite questions despite all attempts to be highly selective in favoriting questions.Taking out hard-prints or pdf prints makes categorizing and searching much more tiresome.

I just don't know how to categorize my favorite questions based on aspects of a language like `functions`,`global variables`,`recursion`,`syntax` and other categories. It is really going to be a headache as I find good questions to add to the list everyday.Due to time constraints I can't read and assimilate the answers rightaway and have to `bookmark`/`favorite` them for later reference.

I am sure it's common problem and there must be a solution for this on StackOveflow.I tried looking for it and couldn't find.So please suggest me the best option available to users for this issue.

Comment: If it's a duplicate please link to the original question with the best answers.

Comment: The only similar question is from 2009.

Comment: Perhaps this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3912/196875 or this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15504/196875. Although SO does not have a feature that you seek, the second link offers a workaround.

Comment: @IceMAN They seem good but are from 2009,just a year after SO's creation.I am sure things would have changed a lot in 3.5 years

Comment: Yes, they are old enough. But I find using the workaround quite effective. Unfortunately, if no such feature exists, you make the best of what you can, however you can do it. ;-)

Comment: Related / possible duplicate - [Allow grouping of favorite questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125180/allow-grouping-of-favorite-questions)

Answer (score 4):

Why not use the solution you mention: **bookmarking**?

Favoriting is important if you want to see when questions are changed, but you said "for later reference" which sounds like updates aren't the main priority for you.

Your browser supports folders for bookmarks, so just make whatever folders you want and then put bookmarked posts in the appropriate ones.  No extra SO functionality required.

Comment: This idea seems good while SO comes up with a better one

Comment: Thanks, was in plain sight. However something native to SO would be ideal. Wouldn't need to worry about syncing book marks across devices/browsers