# Is there a way to sort questions I have starred and find interesting?

Tags: feature-request, tags, bookmarks

Recently, I have been finding a lot of cool questions on Stack Overflow. I am very into Ruby, Java and JavaScript, but after only recently finding many cool questions I have found that the things I have starred as favorites are kind of just randomly ordered. This of course becomes especially annoying if you start starring tons of questions.

It would be nice if there was a way that I can have a column or something like that where I can put the cool questions I found on Ruby. Then another for Java etc. Of course there are some questions on SO that are not so much language specific, but it would be nice to have a way to organize this so that later when I want to see a specific cool question from Ruby I can already filter the Java questions out. Right now I just put all these links into an Excel file and have some headers.

Comment: At this point, you're better off with the bookmarking features provided by your browser.

Comment: I think my question has been asked here actually I just found one http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15504/create-a-better-way-to-organize-favorites?rq=1, this can probably be closed