# Introducing the possibility of creating folders in favorites section

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bookmarks

I tried to see if it is possible to create folders in the section of favorites, to organise the related question in different topics. Personally I have saved different questions because I still can't understand them properly but many of these could really help me in future, but in this way the section gets quite confusing, allowing to create folders and name them could help to give a lot of order. I think this could be a good tool, obviously it is just a suggestion, I am not expecting anything but if it is something that a big part of the community would appreciate maybe could be considered.

I am aware that this has been discussed in the past in the following links, thanks to the clarification given on the same question I posed (wrongly) on th PSE [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12875/introducing-the-possibility-of-creating-folders-in-the-favorites-section). The following are some links to discussions of this type

[Create a better way to organize favorites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15504/create-a-better-way-to-organize-favorites)

[Better favourites organisation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/better-favourites-organisation)

[Organizing favorite questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7752/organizing-favorite-questions)

but since these discussions are quite old and as new features concernig the favorites section should come out in this period as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345148/upcoming-feature-follow-questions), maybe it could be possible reconsider an introduction of tools like folders (just as an example) or whatever the community feels more adapt to cover this kind of problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: Favorites aren't meant to replace your browsers bookmark feature.

Comment: The ["main" request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/better-favourites-organisation) is wrongly marked as completed, so can't close as duplicate of it. Found one asking for the same thing as you ask for which isn't marked as completed or rejected though.

Comment: Also related: [Favorites improvements - search, categorize, personal tags, add note, favorite answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75944). (One answer mentions a GreaseMonkey script available on Stack Apps - but I did not manage to get it working: [Favourites Enhancer: Tag favourites and add personal notes](https://stackapps.com/q/6215).)

Comment: Alternatively, tagging of favourites (like for questions).

Comment: [Related answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347589/184688).