# Manage my favorite with custom folders or custom tags

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Better Favourites Organisation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/better-favourites-organisation)

I think SO users need the ability to manage the favorite in custom folders or tags. The problem is that if I want to go back to any one of them I couldn't find it because I had a lot of favorite questions.

Do you think it would be handy?