# Repost of watch vs favorite

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Subscribing to questions and comments that don't belong to you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45360/subscribing-to-questions-and-comments-that-dont-belong-to-you)

I know this has been brought up before.
I firmly believe there is a difference between a "Favorite" question (the little star) and a "Watch" (maybe some binoculars).

Today I was reading a jquery question that dealt with fading in and out and how document load works, etc etc.  I started to answer it AND I even commented on it..
2 minutes later I went back to the question and re-read it...Shoot I thought I misread the question so I deleted my comment AND I deleted my answer..

This question I do not consider a "Favorite" but I would consider it something interesting...
I can't "Watch" this question...and no @Jeff Atwood, I do not want to temporarily add it to my favorites and then remove it, to me it is not a favorite.

Now I wanted to go back and see whatever ended up with this question.  For the life of me I can't find it because 1) I deleted my comment and 2) I deleted the actual answer to my question.  Hence, now I cannot find it because there are probably 500,000 jquery questions.

Can we please add a feature "Watch" kind of like http://www.quora.com/.  I love that site because it has a watch feature.  Stackoverflow developers / admins, please do not just close my question without an answer of why you think a watch is the same as a favorite.

Comment: is there some reason you can't just bookmark it in your browser, if you are so religiously opposed to marking it as a favorite? I think you're creating a problem that doesn't exist..

Comment: @Jeff Atwood - So my browser is responsible for managing thousands of "interesting" stack exchange questions...real nice.

Comment: see http://stackexchange.com/users/ae91127f-3a9c-41e0-9385-bdea7593069c?tab=favorites

Answer (score 5):

First, I think you're getting too caught up in the semantics of the word "Favorites."  In Web parlance it's just another word for "bookmarked for later," so I do think being able to star a question temporarily as a "Favorite" is a perfectly valid reason not to also add a "Watch" list.  We already have one.

In addition to that, you can follow the [RSS feed of any question you like](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/106188) in the RSS reader of your choice.  The feed link is at the bottom right of the page.

Comment: Man, that question feed button needs to be *bigger.* I can't believe I've never seen it before!

Comment: @Chris: No! Smaller, and fade the color more!  ;)

Comment: -1 but it is NOT a favorite, I only would like to see if they understood the problem and the possible answers.  To me it isn't a favorite.  If we don't pay attention to the semantics of the word favorite than it causes all the more confusion.  Instead of 10 favorites I could potentially have 10,000.  Have you ever scrolled through 10,000 favorites in google chrome / ie?

Comment: @JohH: Again, you're too caught up in the word "favorite." Nobody is saying that it's your favorite question in the whole wide world if you star it.  We're not even saying that you *like* it.  Just that you're keeping an eye on it.  You can just click the star again to undo a favorite.

Comment: @Bill please see my edit...the point is WE should get caught up in the wording, I don't care if you want to change the word from favorite to bookmark, it still doesn't answer my question.  I could have 10,000 bookmarks, but out of those 10k I have 20 favorites.

Comment: @JonH RSS feed != favorite, and you can use your favorite feed reader to keep tabs on the questions you're interested in.

Comment: @JohH: Do you think a Watch list with 10,000 questions would be any different than 10,000 favorites?

Comment: @Bill the Lizard - `You can just click the star again to undo a favorite` no really you should read my post, that is exactly opposite of what I want to do.  Don't force the user to do more work, it's a horrible UI decision.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard - Having a list of 10,000 bookmarks is not ok....hence why should a favorite be lumped in with something that is not a favorite.  Out of my 10,000 bookmarks, I have 10 favorites, why is it so hard to implement such a thing?

Comment: Can we get Facebook to add an "Acquaintance" category, too, while we're arguing about semantics?

Comment: @Wooble - enter google+, that is exactly my point...if you are making it a joke.  Competitors take people out by researching the UI or the mishaps of others.  I am not saying this is just as big, but because we assume or "get caught up with the semantics" that is where the issue lies.  In your example, because facebook doesn't have these special groups / lists google+.  The result of this is people on facebook could and eventually will leave that in the dust and join a more logical more UI appreciative solution.

Comment: @Wooble - take a gander at quora and see how they handle this.  The link is in my original question.

Comment: @JohH: You can undo the star *when you're done watching the question*.  How else would you make the UI work?  It's one click.  If you don't make yourself clear then rereading your question doesn't help.

Comment: @JonH: No, you remove the star whenever you choose to.  You never have to lose it at all.  If you only have 10 questions that are your "real" favorites, then why haven't you bookmarked them in your browser, or on your Google home page?

Comment: @JohH: Both IE and Chrome support bookmark folders.  I don't know if either one has a limit on the number of pages you can bookmark.

Comment: @JonH: You could try searching. Honestly, the tools you need are already there, you're just refusing to use them. How much effort do you think other people should put in to helping you when you won't help yourself?

Comment: (cont...) manage my bookmarks, especially across multiple stackexchange sites.  What do you see wrong with the concept of bookmarks and favoriting a bookmark?  Simple concept, effective, searchable based on type.  Let's assume we take your advise and favorite anything we find interesting and thing that we really believe are favorites.  Assume we have over 50k...(we really love so and we love technology so we watch and favorite a lot).  Without the seperation of the two how much better is search exactly?  Think about search within the bookmarks (would you like to search within 50k or 10...

Comment: (cont...)if I had 10 favorites within my 50k bookmarks and I lump them all into one category and I really am looking for a question that I know that I've favorited.  I am searching for 49,990 more records then I need to.