# Categorizing Favorites

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Better Favourites Organisation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/better-favourites-organisation)

Is there any way to organize favorites??

Like people have mentioned that having tags or placing the favorites in folders would be a good idea.  Is that something that is being developed?

Comment: Related: [Better Favourites Organisation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3912) (possible duplicate; the oldest I could find).

Comment: yep, i went through that thread.  i like the idea of tags, but was wondering if some way of categorizing would be introduced soon.

Comment: It's best if you provide the links you already read in your question, and comment on why you still need to ask a new question (as you now did in your comment).