# Better way to sift through favorites and search correct fit to the problem at hand

Tags: feature-request, search, bookmarks

Can there be a search option when trying to go through my "Favorite" questions? If I have a lot of questions marked as favorite, it is quite a task to go through them and check if I have already an answer to a question that I currently have.

We can have a search box, where we can type tags that might describe the problem we have at hand and it returns the list of favorite questions which "might" fit our description thereby reducing the time required to zero in on the correct "answer" question.

It will help find/manage content better, IMHO.

A related question: [Better favourites organisation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/better-favourites-organisation)